# Convertir string numérico a una cadena de 12 caracteres

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un problema, estoy necesitando convertir un valor que llega de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])){
    $total_price = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product){
    $total_price += ($product["price2"]*$product["quantity"]);
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
    $total_price_Envio = $total_price + 5;
    $subTotal = money_format('%(#10n',$total_price_Envio) . "\n";
                                        ?>
```

El usuario logra visualizar lo siguiente en la interfaz ($ 300.00), pero para trabajarlo necesito escitamente que sea convertido de la siguiente manera:

```
$amount = '000000030000';
```

Ayúdenme a convertirlo por favor.

Comment: $subTotal me imprime en pantalla $ 300.00, yo lo necesito convertir a 000000030000

Comment: Entonces `$total_price_Envio` te imprime 300.00?

Comment: $total_price_Envio es un valor extra que le sumo de $ 5.00, eso lo calcula automáticamente.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Hay un dato original con el que se pueda trabajar, sin someterlo a `money_format`? ¿En qué contexto necesitas que el valor sea `000000030000`, en PHP o en JS? ¿Por qué necesitas los `0` a la izquierda? Pulsa en [edit]  para aclarar la pregunta, no en comentarios.

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, lamento la carencia de detalles, el código de arriba corresponde a un desarrollo en PHP, el valor antes de convertirlo con money_format viene desde una DB y necesito que el formato sea 000000030000 dado que es para una pasarela de pagos.

Comment: @user3033258 edita tu pregunta y coloca esos detalles, ademas indica cual es el valor original que te da 300.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
$filled_int = sprintf("%04d", 10);

echo $filled_int; //result: 0010
```

[sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) te permite devolver una cadena formateada a partir de un valor. En este caso el primer parametro `"%04d"` representa el valor a recibir; el `0` representa el caracter de relleno a utilizar, el 4 la cantidad de caracteres a mostrar y finalmente la  `d` indica que el valor recibido sera tratado como un `integer`. El segundo parámetro `10` es el valor a formatear.

Suerte!

Answer (score -1):

Si lo estas leyendo o cargando desde la base de datos, yo hago lo siguiente para mostrar una cadena rellenada con ceros por la izquierda desde que se procesa el dato en la consulta:

```html
            $etiquetaActivosResguardo=str_pad($resultadoActivosResguardo[$i]->getEnteroActivo(),12,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $etiquetaActivosResguardo.=str_pad($resultadoActivosResguardo[$i]->getEnteroSubActivo(),4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Esto concatena dos valores que existen la bd, y les coloca ceros por la izquierda dando por resultado por ejemplo:  0000101165680000  y 0000101165680001

En el primer caso, toma de la base el 10116568 y lo rellena en 12 posiciones entonces como le faltan 4 dígitos, le pone los 4 ceros quedando así : 000010116568, y el segundo valor que puede ser un 0 o un 1 según sea el caso, también rellena y coloca los ceros faltantes, como se indica 4 posiciones, entonces te pone para el caso de 0, los tres ceros faltantes quedando 0000 y en el caso del 1, entonces quedaría 0001, una vez que hace esto, claro que para mi caso debo juntar ambos números para formar una sola cadena para que sea mostrada en una tabla, y queden así: en el caso que traiga cero =  0000101165680000  y en el caso que traiga 1 = 0000101165680001.

Aquí te dejo una referencia: [Rellenar un string](https://manuales.guebs.com/php/function.str-pad.html)

Ya teniendo el valor rellenado ya lo puedes ocupar en donde necesites, lo mandas como variable, en un input, lo puedes mandar a pantalla o como tu lo requieras